# Differences between caret notation and ANSI escape sequence

Tags: shell, terminal, colors

My question is raised from two different observations.

In `cat`, when I press `ESC` or other control keys, Bash uses caret notation to represent them. The figure tells I pressed ESC key, but Bash shows it as `^[`.

[image]

Nevertheless, if I want to write colorful text in scripts, by `echo` for instance, it seems I have to use ANSI escape sequence.

[image]

The figure shows that caret notation does not work in `echo`, but ANSI escape sequence does.

Can I say that we must use ANSI escape sequence to **enter** ESC key, but Bash will use caret notation to **represent** it?

Is there a way to enter ESC key by caret notation? Can Bash represent an entered key in ANSI escape sequence?

Note I'm actually using ZSH. You are fine to talk about either shell.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text...

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't think I'm able to write text in color on SO.

Comment: @Gqqnbig: I suggest that you remove either the zsh or the bash tag and focus on one shell at a time only.

Answer (score 4):

If you type

$ echo '<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd>[31mhello'

and when done it will show you

```
$ echo '^[[31mhello'
```

You probably need `set -o vi` in bash.

However, the best way to do that would be to use `tput`:

```
$ tput setaf 9; echo hello; tput sgr0
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out ctrl-v, _quoted-insert: Add the next character typed to the line verbatim._

Answer (score 1):

> Can I say that we must use ANSI escape sequence to enter ESC key

No, with special keyboard or configuration you can enter `\033` byte from your keyboard just like any other character.

> , but Bash will use caret notation to represent it?

I believe Bash does not use caret notation. The *terminal* when displaying unhanded ESC character when executing a program displays it as `^[`. You can execute `sleep 20` and press ESC with same result. You can execute your terminal window without bash with `sleep 20` and it will also print `^[` when pressing ESC.

> Is there a way to enter ESC key by caret notation?

I do not know any programs that would do that, but writing a short script to convert caret notation to bytes is minutes of work. `sed 's/\^\[/\x1b/g' <<<'^[[31mhello'` for starters, but a python script would be more versatile.

> Can Bash represent an entered key in ANSI escape sequence?

ANSI escape sequence *are* the bytes, so however you represent it in any representation it's still is going to be an escape sequence. Yes, bash can represent ANSI escape sequence. In `set -x` output bash outputs just bytes as they are:

```
$ bash -c "( set -x; echo $'\033[33afds' )" 2>&1 | hexdump -C
00000000  2b 20 65 63 68 6f 20 27  1b 5b 33 33 61 66 64 73  |+ echo '.[33afds|
#                                  ^^ - raw byte in bash set -x output
00000010  27 0a 1b 5b 33 33 61 66  64 73 0a                 |'..[33afds.|
0000001b
```

the builtin `printf` represents `0x1b` byte as `\E`:

```
$ printf "%q\n" $'\033[33mhello'
$'\E[33mhello'
```

External printf uses different notation:

```
$ /bin/printf "%q" $'\033[33mhello'
''$'\033''[33mhello'
```

Bash quoting expansion is same as builtin printf:

```
$ v=$'\033[33mhello'; echo "${v@Q}"
$'\E[33mhello'
```

---

Overall cat output is unrelated to ANSI escape sequences. Data representation is irrelevant to data. Whatever you choose in any notation to represent your data it's still the same bytes...

Comment: Thanks you for answering my each and every question. It seems I can conclude that the last step to enter ESC to bash/Linux/terminal is to use ANSI escape sequence. Your `sed` example converts ^[ to ANSI, then sends to Bash, unless you show a shell or a famous program that directly works on caret notation, that your sed converts ANSI to caret.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand the basic concepts. Does "notation“ mean to represent things while "escape" mean input? Hence it makes nonsense to ask Bash/Terminal/Linux to use "escape" to represent things?

Comment: `then sends to Bash` no, it outputs it, on the terminal. Bash only redirected output of the program to the terminal, the data does not go through shell, they are displayed as they are. `that your sed converts ANSI to caret` I do not understand, it converts two characters `^[` into byte `\x1b` nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: `Does "notation“ mean to represent things while "escape" mean input?` Escape means usually to prepend characters with another character to notify reader of a special meaning. Notation would be a standard way of representing things. Is 27 equal to `0x1b` equal to `\033`? It's the exact same number _represented_ with different "notation", where `\0` and `0x` are escape sequences to denote octal and hex number.  We humans use base-10 "notation" to represent numbers. 27 in base-10 is also equal to `^[` in caret.